# Do you add the Strength DM to melee damage in Mongoose Traveller?

Tags: mongoose-traveller

Everyone from the wimpiest schoolkid from a low gravity planet to the biggest, buffest bodybuilder from a high gravity planet appears to do 1d6 damage when they punch someone. Should we be adding the Strength DM to the damage roll?

I can't find anything relevant in the rulebook. I've got Mongoose Traveller 1e but am happy to use rules from 2e if there are some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 1st Edition Mongoose Traveller, **you do not add your strength DM to melee damage.**

It's incorporated into your roll to-hit, which indirectly affects damage.

On page 61 of the core rulebook:

> The standard skill checks used in making an attack are:
>
> **Melee attack = 2d6 + Melee (appropriate specialty) + Strength or Dexterity DM (attacker's choice)**

Subsequently, on page 65, under **Damage**:

> Each weapon lists the damage it inflicts as a number of d6. Add the Effect of the attack roll to this damage.

The usual target number is 8+, so to hit someone you're wanting your total to be 8 or more (plus or minus whatever situational modifiers are going on).

The Effect here is the margin of success of the the attack (p50, *Effect* section). So for every point you get over 8 on your dice roll you inflict an extra point of damage. **This means that high strength increases both your accuracy and maximum damage**, but only if you choose to use your Strength DM for the attack roll.

In summary: **When rolling to hit in melee, use the better of your Strength or Dexterity DMs. Don't apply Strength to the final damage total.**

Comment: Wow! I think my players are about to abruptly become much more dangerous in bar brawls.

Comment: In my opinion it's a little bit strange that being super-beefy makes you more accurate when punching/stabbing people, but there's a precedent in Dungeons and Dragons and it lets you play beefy bruiser archetypes without them also having to be ninjas in order to hit anything. Plus in game-balance terms it means Dexterity isn't a complete must-have for all forms of combat.

Answer (score 6):

From p74 of e2 core rulebook

> Melee Attacks
>   When a melee attack is successful, the attacker adds
>   their STR DM to the damage rolled for the weapon.
>   Bigger things hit harder!